# how to sending ejs tag data to javascript?

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <script>
        var ajax_get_api_data = [1,2,3]
        <% var dataArray = ajax_get_api_data %>
    </script>

   <% dataArray.map((data) => {%>
    <div><%=data%></div>
   <%}) %>


</body>
</html>
```

My intend of Question is for Sending script data to EJS tag

I hope to get datas by calling ajax get api on script tage then I hope to send ajaxCalling data to EJS.

I tryed like above but only to fail.

How can i fix it .

I know that it will fix simply by

```
<% var ajax_get_api_data = [1,2,3] %>
```

but it isn`t what i want. beacuse ajax_get_api_data is from script tag not ejs tag

How can i transmit  script data to EJS

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are mistaken about how ejs works.

the javascript inside <% %> is ran when you render the page
the part inside script tags is ran client side

so a

```
<script>
 var ajax_get_api_data = [1,2,3] // client side
 <% var dataArray = ajax_get_api_data %> // undefined during rendering

</script>
```

instead you want

```
 <script>
 var ajax_get_api_data = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(dataArray) %>')

</script>
```

explanation :
you pass the data from server as a string (using JSON.stringify) to the client and use JSON parse to transform it back in to a array